# What should be my approach if I am not given proper KRAs?

Tags: manager, review

I had two to three meetings with my manager but he did not give me proper Key Result Areas (KRAs) for the current financial year, instead, he told me to learn Microsoft Azure. As per my understanding, this is not a KRA.

Please suggest how should I approach my manager again on this challenge.

Comment: I can just about Google "KRA", but what is "Micro Azure"? How do you know that isn't a KRA for the company this year?

Comment: Sorry, this is learning Microsoft Azure, A Cloud technology, but can learning a technology be the only KRA for entire year

Comment: 1) So please call it "Microsoft Azure" or just "Azure". [Making up your own name for something](https://www.google.com/search?q=%2B%22micro+azure%22) doesn't help anyone else understand what you're asking about. 2) Maybe learning Azure is *really* important to your employer this year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Set your own goals.**

If your manager can't come up with things they need you to do - **invent them yourself**, and get management to accept those targets. I would suggest **preparing more options to choose from**, and set up a meeting to discuss what is best suited for you in current company situation.

If that meeting doesn't solve your problem - at least it should give you and your manager a good direction to move forward.